# Add tag "midao"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

I am new to StackOverflow and I wonder if it is possible to add tag "**midao**" ?
The reason for this request is that there is Java Open-Source project called Midao ([www.midao.org](http://midao.org)) and it would be great to be able to ask questions / find answers by using that tag.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I already investigated [Help Center > Privileges > Create Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), and according to information there - I don't have enough privileges to create it myself.

Comment: We can't add tags (not even moderators) until there is at least one question where that tag would fit. [Quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=midao) show there's still not a single question, so once there is let us know (edit your post with link to the question) and high rep user can create the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't.

You need to have at least one (preferably a few more) questions *about* Midao to be able to create the tag. But currently there are [**no** questions even mention Midao](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=midao).

Ask questions, just tag with [java](/questions/tagged/java), and earn some reputation. Then when you have a decent body of questions, you perhaps have the rep yourself to add the tag, or you can come back and request it be added.

Comment: 1500 is not just "some reputation", would be much much faster to have existing user with enough rep add the tag, in my opinion this is totally valid request.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: **What questions** do you suggest to add the tag *to*?

Comment: I agree with the first part of your post and written exactly that in a comment, just not really agree with the second part asking the user to wait until he gets 1500 reputation. Once there is such a question, it's totally valid to come back here, edit with link and ask someone to add the tag.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Hopefully will come back here, when it would make sense to create a tag (enough questions etc.)...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: agreed, I actually thought it was lower. Adjusted the wording.

Comment: Cheers @Martijn, it's indeed lower here on Meta (500 rep needed) or smaller sites (e.g. [only 300](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/)), but on the main site it's much higher due to the amount of questions.